# Live USB system with the newest kernel?

Tags: kernel, live-usb

With the newest kernel 4.10 just released I was wondering whether it is possible to download (if yes, where?) a live system of Ubuntu like (16.04 LTS) onto a USB drive but with the newest kernel?

Alternatively could I use the standard live system 16.04 LTS and boot from it and then just upgrade the kernel?

Comment: Linux Kernel 4.10 is in Ubuntu 17.04, currently in pre-release testing. It will be released, along with an easy-to-use LiveUSB image, in April 2017. Pre-release versions of Ubuntu are *not supported* and may break your system...that's why highly-skilled volunteers are testing it and fixing the bugs they find. If you are not a highly-skilled tester, we strongly suggest you wait for release.

Comment: Can you upgrade the kernel from 16.04? No, not without breaking your system...unless you are highly skilled.

Comment: @user535733 I thought 17.04 would be based on the 4.9 kernel version, did they upgrade?

Comment: The plan is to push 4.10 into zesty. As of 19 Feb 2017, 4.9 is in zesty, and 4.10 is already in zesty-proposed.

Comment: You can install 16.04 from live USB and then upgrade the kernel to 4.9.10. Upgrading to 4.10.x is not a good idea because it would probably be buggy. Do you have a particular reason for needing a newer kernel?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix actually I just wanted to test the enhanced driver support for the microsoft surface devices, like pen and touch support. So installing and then upgrading is out of question right now, too much of a hassle. I guess I just wait for the official 17.04 release to test it then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the existing ISO9660-based live operating systems provide a kernel update feature: the kernel and the initrd are the only components that a live operating system cannot update, because they lay outside of the data persistence partition (if any) and the system partition is, as said, ISO9660-formatted.

After some years of asking me why, I found the **liveng** whitepaper on Read the Docs.

> The full aim of the liveng project is to give the Community a set of
>   best practices in order to turn a common Debian Linux live into a
>   live(ng) operating system which features:
>
> ```
> native encrypted persistence;
> kernel update (on a live ISO 9660 filesystem!);
> UEFI, with UEFI Secure Boot compatibility, with a real efi partition.
> ```